# Is there a way to call ExecuteQuery on a SQL DataContext and return a Tuple instead of a class/object

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to run essentially following query :

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> Details = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
try
{
   using (DataContext context = new DataContext(connectionString))
   {
      string query = @"SELECT [ID],
                              [NAME]
                       FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
                       WHERE [OTHER_ID] = {0}";

      Details = context.ExecuteQuery<Tuple<int, string>>(query, otherID).ToList();
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw;
}
return Details;
```

This isn't working because a ExecuteQuery is expecting an object that has a parameterless constructor.

Work around right now is really simple : Create a small object instead of this Tuple

OR

Forgo the DataContext and just run the query on a SQLConnection and run a Table adapter over the result.

Due to the nature of the project, I'd like to not have either. Is there anything that will let me return the results of a query to a Tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no implicit conversion from anonymous type to Tuple even with the same types inside.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do this (I tried it and it works):

```
var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
int whatever = 0;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [ NAME ] FROM[ DB ].[ dbo ].[ TABLE ] WHERE[ OTHER_ID ] = @Param1 ";
cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "Param1", whatever ) );
List<object> items = new List<object>();
cmd.Connection.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while( reader.Read() ) {
    items.Add( Tuple.Create<int, int>((int)reader[0], (int) reader[1]) );
}
return items; // you can cast it here to whatever you want
```

Comment: Yes definitely. But I figure the OP knows that.

Comment: noted. but others coming to this answer in the future may not and it would be in bad faith to let them copy this in it's current state. would take much for you to improve on this answer.

Comment: @Nkosi Good idea. Edited and added parameters.